# Error in as.owin Handling shape files in the spatstat package R

Tags: r, shapes, point, polygons, spatstat

I´m trying to follow the tutorial ["Handling shape files in the spatstat package" by Adrian Baddeley](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatstat/vignettes/shapefiles.pdf) where a shape as SpatialPolygonsDataFrame is converted to a collection of owin´s.

The key attributes of shape are summarized below and my objective is to test whether a collection of points are within a collection of polygons.

> summary(shape)

```
Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates:
        min       max
x -43.13679 -42.95351
y -22.98961 -22.85380
Is projected: FALSE 
proj4string : [+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs]
```

it has 907 polygons 
here are the suggested transformations

```
cp <- as(shape, "SpatialPolygons")
cregions <- slot(cp, "polygons")
cregions <- lapply(cregions, function(x) { SpatialPolygons(list(x)) })
cwindows <- lapply(cregions, as.owin)
```

but I get the error

```
Error in as.owin.default(X[[1L]], ...) : Can't interpret W as a window
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What do you get for `class(cregions)` ?  There may be something unintended in your conversion to `SpatialPolygons` or from there to `polygons` .

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same error message:

```
class(cregions[[1]])
```

[1] "SpatialPolygons"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"

I think it has to do with errors in topology.  I got it to work with this (abeit homemade) function:

```
fixholes = function(sp.obj) {
  require(rgeos)
  require(stringr)
  if(!inherits(sp.obj, "SpatialPolygons")) stop("Input object must be of class SpatialPolygons")
  pls = slot(sp.obj, "polygons")
  pls1 = lapply(pls, checkPolygonsHoles)
  slot(sp.obj, "polygons") = pls1
  return(sp.obj)
}
```

I then created a function to employ Adrian Baddeley's routine detailed in "Handling shapeﬁles in the spatstat package":

```
spdf2owin = function(spdf) {
  cp <- as(spdf, "SpatialPolygons")
  cregions <- slot(cp, "polygons")
  cregions <- lapply(cregions, function(x) { fixholes(SpatialPolygons(list(x))) })
  cwindows <- lapply(cregions, as.owin)
  ch <- hyperframe(window=cwindows)
  ch <- cbind.hyperframe(ch, spdf@data)
  return(ch)
}
```

For example,

`cregions = spdf2owin(columbus)`

Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

The package `maptools` must be loaded in order to convert `sp` classes to `spatstat` classes.

`as.owin` is a generic function defined in `spatstat`. Some methods for `as.owin` are provided in `spatstat`; other methods are provided in `maptools`. In order to convert a `SpatialPolygons` to an `owin`, the method `as.owin.SpatialPolygons` must be available, and this is provided by `maptools`. If `maptools` is not loaded, the call to `as.owin` will dispatch to `as.owin.default` and give the error message which you got.